Установщик Дебиана не видит установочный носитель
У меня Windows. Я пытался сделать Dual Boot с Linux Debian. Что бы было понятнее что будет далее, скажу что флешки у меня нету и как установочный носитель я использовал отдельный раздел на диске. Я загружаюсь на файл /EFI/grubx64.efi и запускаю установку, а когда наступает момент, где там че то с установочным носителем делают, мне пишет что установочный носитель не найден. Помогите пожалуйста.
